# Methods in yacc to get line no

Tags: bison, yacc

What are the different ways of getting line no's in yacc. I know about yylineno but it can be off by 1 when yacc reads lookahead token.

I had this same problem with using yytext in yacc. It didn't give the expected token. I used yylval.str in lex to get that done. Is there anything similar to that to get exact line no.

Are there better options in Bison which can make handling easier and accurate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The role of a scanner is to produce a sequence of lexical tokens, each of which has a type, a semantic value, and possibly a location. The parser receives this stream of tokens, and processes them into a structural representation of the input.

It should be clear that in the parser, "the last semantic value scanned" is of little or no value, particularly since the parser usually needs to ask the scanner to look ahead at least one token in order to decide how to proceed. But more generally, a parser action will be combining information about a series of tokens (and a series of already reduced productions), so there is no "one value" which makes sense in the action.

Similarly, every token has a location in the input, and if the parser needs to associate locations with syntax features, it needs to be able to refer to the location of any given token.

Bison facilitates this process by allowing the scanner to fill in a [location object](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Tracking-Locations) as well as a semantic value (`yylval`). The location object is called `yylloc` and, unlike the semantic value, it is normally the same type for every token. If your Bison source uses locations, it will create a location object stack which is synchronized with the semantic value stack. In a rule, the semantic value of a token (or non-terminal) can be referred to as `$1`, `$2`, etc.; similarly, the location of the token/non-terminal will be `@1`, `@2`, ...

You don't need to tell Bison to collect location information. It will happen automatically if you simply use some location reference (`@n`) in any parser action.

In fact, you don't need to do much in your parser to make use of location information, since the defaults are often sufficient. Unless you `#define` the preprocessor macro `YYLTYPE`, a location object type called `YYLTYPE` will be declared as follows:

```
typedef struct YYLTYPE {
  int first_line;
  int first_column;
  int last_line;
  int last_column;
} YYLTYPE;
```

The declaration will be placed into the generated header file so that it can be used by the scanner as well. The `YYLTYPE` structure reflects the fact that a token -- and, more importantly, a non-terminal -- spans a range of locations in the source file.

The location structure for a non-terminal will be also be filled in automatically by the generated parser, although you are free to modify it by assigning to `@$` inside a parser action. The default is to take the `first_line` and `first_column` fields from `@1` and the `last_line` and `last_column` fields from `@n`, where *n* is the number of symbols in the right-hand side. In other words, when you reduce a production, the resulting location will span all of the source text representing the tokens of the production.

Although `yylloc` contains both line and column information, you are not required to use the column data. It is most convenient to just leave those fields set to 0, in case you want to use them in some later version of your parser; you could reduce the overhead of the location stack by redefining `YYLTYPE`, but then you would need to override the default location action as well because it refers to those named fields.

Filling in the `yylloc` object is entirely the responsibility of your scanner, and flex does not, unfortunately, help you much. Flex will maintain `yylineno` if you ask it to (`%option yylineno`) but it won't populate `yylloc`, so you need to do that yourself. Fortunately, flex does let you define the [`YY_USER_ACTION`](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Misc-Macros.html) macro. This macro is inserted at the beginning of *every* flex action, and it can be used to copy location information into `yylloc`.

As a simple example, if none of your tokens span more than one line (or you don't care about the starting line of tokens which do span more than one line), you could simply put this in the prologue of your flex definition:

```
#define YY_USER_ACTION yylloc.first_line = yylloc.last_line = yylineno;
```

and enable `yylineno` tracking with

```
%option yylineno
```

Once you've done that, and with no other changes to your flex or bison definitions, you'll be able to write actions such as:

```
assignment: IDENTIFIER '=' expression {
               printf("%s is defined at line %d\n", $1, @1.first_line);
            }
```

Note that since the above rule refers to the location of the `IDENTIFIER` token, it does not matter how many lines the `expression` uses up. You could make use of the default setting of `@$` to be more precise:

```
assignment: IDENTIFIER '=' expression {
               printf("%s is defined in lines %d to %d\n",
                      $1, @$.first_line, @$.last_line);
            }
```